# Ionic DateTime Sensitivity

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-native, ionic6

I am using Ionic 6 with Angular 14.

Is there a way to make the Ionic Time Picker less sensitive? The wheel scrolls very fast and makes it very difficult to stop on the correct hour/minute.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime

The iOS mode works much better than the Android one, but still oversensitive. The touch area is also quite small, so the user's finger typically covers the digits of the hour/minutes wheel, making it difficult to see which value is currently "selected".

[image]

Is there any way to:

1. make the hour/minute wheel less sensitive/scroll slower?
2. make the hour/minute wheel value buttons bigger?

[image]

Please feel free to leave any suggestions for alternative time picker components that function well on iOS, Android and in Browser.

Comment: You cannot change the speeds of the scrolling. The docs don't have anything about this. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime

Comment: @StackoverBlows, yes, I know the docs don't have anything about this, that is why I am asking the stackoverflow community for help with a workaround. Thanks for your input.

Comment: It's not possible.  The ionic components use shadow dom.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible to modify the Ionic datetime component in the way that you want to. Ionic simply doesn’t offer options for that level of customisation and there’s no workaround.

Probably best with a different datetime picker more like what you’re looking for. [Mobiscroll’s offering](https://demo.mobiscroll.com/angular/datetime) seems the most like what you’re looking for but it’s not free.

If that doesn’t work, there are plenty of options if you search “angular datetime picker”.

Sorry it’s not better news!